# Convert inner join native query to jpql

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have this method

```
@Query("select * from feed_tbl feed inner join view_tbl viewers on feed.id <> viewers.feed_id where viewers.user_id = :userId", nativeQuery = true)
fun findAll(@Param("userId") userId: Long): List<Feed>
```

entities:
User,
Feed

view_tbl is JoinTable in user entity

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `not in` construct:

```
select f from Feed f where f not in (
  select u.feeds from User u where u.id = :userId
)
```

Of cause you will need to map `User` to `Feed` as `many-to-many`